# Regular expression Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am learning to use regular expressions and I'm using them to limit the results of a search query by using the REGEXP_LIKE in Oracle 11. Placing an example of the data available, I have the following:

```
Plan navegación 200 MB
Plan navegación 1 GB
Plan navegación 1 GB
Plan de navegacion 3G
Plan de navegacion 4G
Plan de navegacion 3G Empresarial
Plan de navegacion 4G Empresarial
Plan de servicios 3G
Plan de servicios 4G
Plan navegación Datos
```

I want this result is limited to the following (Only 3G, 4G):

```
Plan de navegacion 3G
Plan de navegacion 4G
Plan de navegacion 3G Empresarial
Plan de navegacion 4G Empresarial
```

I am using the following search pattern but I did not properly filtered results:

- Upper(PLAN_GSM),'(NAVEGA){1}|(3G|4G|5G)'
- Upper(PLAN_GSM),'*((NAVEGA)+)*(3G|4G)+'

I have done several tests and do not find the solution. Someone could give me hints?

Comment: Please show us the complete SQL statement you use

Comment: ... `REGEXP_LIKE(PLAN_GSM, '^Plan de navegacion (3|4|5)G(*)')`

Comment: or simply no regex, just LIKE ...

Comment: One of the querys I used is as follows: 

SELECT * 
Mhp.mhp_postpago FROM PARTITION (MHP_POSTPAGO_1013) 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (Upper (PLAN_GSM) '* ((SAILS) +) * (3G | 4G) +') 

Thank you very much for your kind replies, I've tried all and the filter don't working completely. Any other ideas please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use LIKE, as below:

```
select *
from mytable
where PLAN_GSM LIKE 'Plan de navegacion _G%';
```

or use REGEXP_LIKE, as below:

```
select *
from mytable
where REGEXP_LIKE(PLAN_GSM, '^Plan de navegacion (3|4|5)G(*)');
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6365c/1)</kbd>

**Reference**:

[Oracle/PLSQL: REGEXP_LIKE Condition on Tech on the Net](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php)

Comment: Just `REGEXP_LIKE(text, 'navegacion (3|4|5)G')` ? [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(mycolumn, '\APlan de navegacion \dG.*\z', 'c');
```

- `\d` represents a digit
- `\A` is the beginning of the string
- `.*` greedily matches any characters
- `\z` is the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from all_tab_columns 
where COLUMN_NAME like '%MAIN%ACCOUNT%LINK%CODE%N%' and TABLE_NAME like 'CB%' and not regexp_like(table_name,'[0-9]')
```

The above query will fetch the only object without number of content.

```
select *
from all_tab_columns 
where COLUMN_NAME like '%MAIN%ACCOUNT%LINK%CODE%N%' and TABLE_NAME like 'CB%' and not regexp_like(table_name,'[0-9]')
```

The above query will fetch only object with numbers content.